# Number of subscribed and unsent topic messages in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I've setup a simple chat application using ActiveMQ as a broker of messages. A chat is a topic to which both parties can publish messages and both parties subscribe to messages. A message contains some meta-data about the message, like sender and receiver ids. It all works fine.

Now I'd like to find all users that have a chat message waiting, ie they are offline and there is a published message for their topic waiting to be read. These users should receive a notification (to their mobile) using another platform about having a new message to read.

Have searched all ActiveMQ documentation and forums for an answer, but can't find anything (possibly don't understanding). It seems like an obvious query for a MQ to handle...

I'v enabled JMX for the broker and found EnqueueCount/DequeueCount, but that doesn't help much since they count the total number of messages sent (for every subscriber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to find out what messages has been published and what messages has been consumed (and not consumed) you can listen to [advisory messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html).

From your "management-app" subscribe to `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDelivered.Topic` to find out what messages has been delivered.

Then subscribe to `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Topic` to find out what messages has been consumed.

Then you may, perhaps with some amount of work, figure out if there is a messages that has not been consumed within a time frame and some action needs to be taken (notify the user by other means).

You need to enable this in your configuration.

```
<destinationPolicy>
   <policyMap><policyEntries> 
      <policyEntry topic=">" advisoryForConsumed="true" />
   </policyEntries></policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

Comment: Thanks, that might just work. I'll have to look closer on the advisory message content... will report back later.

Comment: Here's my report... I ran into a new problem instead. I'm using MQTT as transport protocol, which turned out not to work with advisory messages (at least from what I can understand about ActiveMQ and all my tests failed too). I ended up redesigning the application and added a few extra topics to which I publish meta data about messages. Similar to how advisory messages work, I guess.

Comment: I've marked this as my answer, since the idea guided me to a working solution. However, please read Matt Pavlovich answer also, as that might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Look into durable subscriptions. This would create a subscription for each user, where the broker keeps track of which consumer has received which messages and supports the "go away for a while" problem.

Extra credit: Use Virtual Topic instead. It is publish to topic -> subscribe from queue(s) semantic.  More flexibility and easier to maintain.

Note: Edited for config sample

```
<broker...>
 .... <!-- be sure to place elements after "<broker>" in alphabetical order -->
 <destinationInterceptors>
      <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
          <virtualDestinations>
             <virtualTopic name=">" prefix="VirtualTopicConsumers.*." selectorAware="false"/>
         </virtualDestinations>
     </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
 </destinationInterceptors>
 ...
</broker>
```

Then set your producer to:

1. Producer destination: topic://My.Topic
2. Subscription 1 destination name:  queue://VirtualTopicConsumers.Sub1.My.Topic
3. Subscription 1 destination name:  queue://VirtualTopicConsumers.Sub2.My.Topic

Comment: Thanks for answering. Don't quite follow the idea of durable subscriptions. A regular topic works well for solving time differences between sender and receiver. Virtual topics seems good for consuming from more than one thread, but how do I get info about remaining messages of a topic?

Comment: The durable subscription maintains a metric of number of messages waiting for consumption. Additionally, the use of a queue in a VirtualTopic approach allows you to use the Queue statistics as an indication of messages remaining to be consumed on a per-subscriber basis

Comment: Sorry about my initial confusion about durable subscriptions, that is what I'm using already. Your virtual-topic-queue-idea might be work, but I have not been able to wrap my head around it just from reading the ActiveMQ docs. The advisory message approach suggested by Petter Nordlander was easier for me.

Comment: karp47: see my updated answer w/ config snippet and sample destination names